# regex is allowing character while using \s

Tags: regex

How do I write a regular expression for checking if the entered value are all white space or empty or digits. In all other cases it will return false. I tried 
`\s*|\d+` which is allowing character values too.

Comment: Please add your language or tool tag to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex `\s*|\d+` just matches 0 or more whitespace or 1 or more digits *anywhere inside an input string* and it may contain whitespace mixed with digits and other characters.

You can use the following regex:

```
^(?:\s+|\d+)?$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xI2mC0/2)

The regex matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:\s+|\d+)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences (due to `(?:...)`**`?`**) of...

  - `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace symbols or
  - `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string

In plain human words,

- `^....$` - make sure we require a full string match, any partial matches inside a string are not allowed
- `(?:...)?` - all the texts matched with the subpatterns inside this group are *optional*, thus allowing an empty string match (i.e. return *true* if the string is empty).